# Expresión regular para redireción hacia barra final (/) slash

Tags: php, regex

Estoy tratando de hacer una expresión regular para unas redirecciones, lo que necesito es que me coja cualquier url de mi web y me la redireccione a la misma pero con la / al final.

Intente algo así pero no me funciona, alguna idea?

```
//si una dirección no acaba con barra
de: !(.*)/
//llevarme esa dirección con la barra final
a: $1/
```

¿Como podría ser? Gracias!

Comment: la exclamación es una errata? a simple vista parece que sobra

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

buscar: `^(.*?)\/?$`

remplazar por: `\1/`

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/abUlVz/1/)